# optimising (cleaning up existing) partitions for a Ubuntu install

Tags: partitioning

I love using Ubuntu.
I HATE installing Ubuntu. because I usually either make a bad installation / partitioning decision OR I cannot figure out how to adjust partitions and disk space.

and here we are again.
I am trying to install on an old outdated Windows 10 system but everything I try to do to adjust these partitions seems to fail.
don't I just want:

1. a partition to maintain Windows (rarely used but sometimes handy when something doesn't work with Linux.
   that 12GB partition looks to already have W10 so I would keep it.
2. a big data partition. there is about 500GB that seem available for that.
3. a ... approx 15-20gb partition for Ubuntu.

why can I not "shrink" the big 500gb data partition to take a chunk for a Ubuntu install partition?

how do I get rid of these little scraps

[image: 500gb partition]

[image: no clue]

Comment: Your question skims the off-topic *rant in disguise* (see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) due to how its written, but even without that, you've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product you're asking about, nor your minimally pasted details don't show (*due to how cut*) if you're trying to resize a in-use partition (*which isn't allowed!*) and details are unclear (*Ubuntu Desktop has recommended a minimum size of 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 but you mention 15-20gb which maybe risky, but it's unclear to me what you're referring to anyway*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484997